# Pass recyclerview swipe event to viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, swipe, touch-event

I have a ViewPager and RecyclerView in the same Activity and both of theese views overlapping(RecyclerView is on front and ViewPager is on behind). My ViewPager swipe works correctly when I swipe on empty space, but when I swipe on RecyclerView, viewpager swipe doesn't work. I have button and seekbar in Recyclerview. I want to pass RecyclerView swipe events to viewpager (except seekbar). So how can i determine if seekbar of recylerview swiped or not ? And how can I pass swipe events of recylerview to viewpager.

My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my java code:

```
imagesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        imagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
        imagesRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
        imagesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Comment: If I am not wrong : you could remove `clickable / focusable` attributes from `RecyclerView` and his parent + remove them from the `ItemView` if there are set. Now you should be able to swipe the `ViewPager`.

Comment: But there is button and seekbar in RecylerView. So I want to handle swipe events on RecyclerView and if it is not on seekbar I want to pass to viewpager.

Comment: Then show us the RecyclerView Item layout

Answer (score 0):

in your recycler view remove

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```